# How can I perform aggregation across two separate columns in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

I have data that looks like this:

```
Table:
City                 Type

Berlin               Employee
Berlin               Customer
Berlin               Supplier
London               Employee
Madrid               Employee
```

... and so on

I want to know which cities have at least one employee, customer, or supplier. I am not sure on how I can structure my aggregate function to do this? Thanks very much!

Comment: what other `Type` values can exist? If each city can only exist with a `Employee`, `Customer` or `Supplier` then you don't need an aggregate. Can you show any more of your dataset? Or do you need to know the cities that have at least one employee AND customer AND supplier, so in your example only Berlin should be returned?

Comment: Hi there - thanks for the comment. No other Type values can exist. Unfortunately I am unable to share more of my dataset but this is all I need. And you're right, I need to know the cities that have at least one of each and Berlin should be returned. I'm not precious though on how this is done - either a list of cities, or as mentioned below a counter of types per city - either way is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use aggregation function

```
select city
    , sum(case when type = 'Employee' then 1 else 0  end) emp
    , sum(case when type = 'Customer' then 1 else 0  end) cust
    , sum(case when type = 'Supplier' then 1 else 0  end) supp
from my_table 
group by  city
```

and having for check the value  (at least one)

```
select city
    , sum(case when type = 'Employee' then 1 else 0  end) emp
    , sum(case when type = 'Customer' then 1 else 0  end) cust
    , sum(case when type = 'Supplier' then 1 else 0  end) supp
from my_table 
group by  city

having emp +cust+supp > 0
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks very much, the code makes sense but this returns a syntax error? Apologies it's on a VDI so I can't copy and paste it, but this doesn't work.. Also, should there be an 'AS' between the closing ) and emp / cust / supp ?

Comment: EDIT: I was making a silly error forgot to remove a comma at the end, this works perfectly :) thanks!